Trying to execute Docker Postgres Code from a .sh file
I'm having a problem with this.
Idea:
I want to execute a sh file at the end of my Docker execution.
The problem this:
sh file
source api/.env

sudo docker exec -it postgres_nuevo env PGPASSWORD="$DB_PASSWORD" psql -h "$DB_HOST" -p "$DB_PORT" -U "$DB_USER" -d "$DB_NAME"

and throw me this error:
" to address: Try againtranslate host name "postgres_nuevo
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The env variables are fine, I tested with a echo and hardcoded them it works. The problem is when you use .env vars.
I don't know if can help but here is my yml.
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        GIT_BRANCH: ${GIT_BRANCH}
        GIT_USER: ${GIT_USER}
        GIT_PASS: ${GIT_PASS}
        GIT_REPO: ${GIT_REPO}
    container_name: api
    networks:
      - proxy-network
      - default
      - datalaketdf
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres_nuevo
      - adminer
    command: >
      sh -c "
        python manage.py makemigrations;
        python manage.py migrate;
        python manage.py makemigrations datawarehouseApp;
        python manage.py migrate datawarehouseApp;
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      "
    restart: always

  postgres_nuevo:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - proxy-network
      - datalaketdf
    container_name: postgres_nuevo
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${API_POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${API_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${API_POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./dumps:/dumps:rw
      - ${RUTA_BACKUPS_DUMPS_LOCAL}:/backups:rw
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
    user: postgres

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    container_name: adminer
    networks:
      - proxy-network
      - datalaketdf
    ports:
      - ${ADMINER_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres_nuevo

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local

networks:
  proxy-network:
    external: true
  datalaketdf:
    external: true

Thanks

You can't ever connect to a database or any other container within the Dockerfile.  What are you hoping to do with that psql command?  You need to do it after the image is built and at least the database container is running; the way you run manage.py migrate at startup time for example will work (I would do the mechanics of this a little differently though).

OH! Now I undertand ... But I can do this Docker start all the containers... and then sudo sql.sh and ... but the problem is even with the container running ,  i cant do it... this problem is when the container is running no in the dockerfile.

Again, what is the goal of the psql command?  You shouldn't normally need docker exec to interact with a database (and you won't be able to run it from within a container).
